# Como montar um campo usando outros três?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho os seguintes campos na base de dados:

```
| id| estados | cidades | categoria |      todosjuntos      |
| 1 | mg      | sao paul| informati | mg/saopaulo/informati |
```

OS 4 primeiros estão populados, porém gostaria de inserir no `todosjuntos` os mesmos dados dos 3. É possivel fazer  direto via SQL?

```
Update tabela set todosjuntos = estados / cidades / categoria Where todosjuntos=' '
```

Seria por aí?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE
   tabela
SET
   todosjuntos = CONCAT( estados, " ", cidades, " ", categoria )
WHERE
   todosjuntos = "";
```

Mas se for rodar a primeira vez, não precisa nem do `WHERE todosjuntos = ""`

Lembre-se de que pode usar outros caracteres no lugar do espaço no `CONCAT`.

O MySQL tem o `CONCAT_WS` também, mas que permite definir o separador apenas uma vez. Usualmente o `CONCAT` tradicional dá mais liberdade para trabalhar neste quesito:

```
todosjuntos = CONCAT_WS( "/", estados, cidades, categoria)
```

Se não for usar o campo com muita frequência, poderia simplesmente pegar os dados na hora do select, desta forma:

```
SELECT CONCAT( estados, " / ", cidades, " / ", categoria ) AS todos FROM tabela;
SELECT CONCAT_WS( " / ", estados, cidades, categoria ) AS todos FROM tabela;
```

Assim não precisaria criar um campo só pra isso.